# How to check that data is deleted or not in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

Yesterday we've added a simple form to our site, and we just implemented an API View using Django which is connected to a PostgreSQL database.
Today I queried the database to see how many rows are submitted, and I encountered a strange thing in the results, We've created and migrated our model using Django ORM, so the primary key is defined as an auto-increment integer field, the problem is row ids are not continuous and they are so diverse, when I'm writing this question, the max id value is 252, but we have only 72 records in the table, 
I've seen this before in other tables, but those tables were subjected to delete and update queries, but we only insert to this new table, and my question is: is our data deleted or it's a normal behavior in PostgreSQL?
I've searched in google and it seems that the only way is to check WAL logs, but we have not enabled that for our database yet, is there another way to check that the data is consistent or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Expect holes in a sequence

If you have multiple connections to a database that are adding rows, then you should expect to see holes in the sequence number results.

If Alice is adding a row, she may bump the sequence from 10 to 11 while not yet doing a COMMIT. Meanwhile, Bob adds a record, bumping the sequence to 12, and assigning 12 to his row, which he now commits. So the database has stored rows with ID field values of 10 and 12, but not 11.

- If Alice commits, then 11 will appear in a query.
- If Alice does a ROLLBACK, then 11 will *never* appear in a query.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I just wanna know is there a way to make sure that this is the case? you're right we are using connection pools, and multiple connection scenario is possible, but we have large gaps e.g. 10 -> 35 or 218 -> 237, and I'm thinking are these gaps normal?